# Order of composition when constructing conformal maps

Tags: complex-analysis

Simple question about how to compose maps: If we want a conformal map mapping the second quadrant $\{x+iy\in\mathbb C:\ x\in (0,-\infty),\ y\in (0,\infty)\}$ onto the upper half-plane $\{x+iy\in\mathbb C:\ y >0\}$ it would seem that we can take different routes.

One way would be to rotate the quadrant via $f_1(z)=-iz$ so we have the first quadrant and then "unfold" it via $f_2(z)=z^2$. In total we get the map $f(z)=(f_2\circ f_1)(z)=-z^2$.

However, one could also first "unfold" via $f_2$ so we get the left half-plane $\{x+iy\in\mathbb C:\ x<0\}$ and then rotate it onto the upper half-plane using $f_1$. Unfortunately the map $g:=f_1\circ f_2$ doesn't really do what $f$ does and I cannot understand why. Why can't we use the rotation as the second step?

Comment: The maps do not commutate. $f_2$ maps the second quadrant to the lower half-plane, then you would have to rotate by 180 degrees, i.e. $z \to -z$, to get the upper half-plane.

Comment: Damn! You're right, $f_2$ doesnt get me the left half-plane. I completely fizzled there. Thanks!